# Sharepoint 2013 Page Viewer bug in IE when viewing pdf

Tags: page-viewer-web-part

I am trying to display a pdf with 3 pages using the Page Viewer webpart. In Chrome it displays all 3 pages at once just like I want it to but in IE 11, it only shows one page at a time and you have to page through them one at a time. I have searched high and low and not found any reference to this problem. Has anyone run into it before? Is there a workaround for IE or a different way to do it.  Note: I have also tried the content control using embed tags with the same result.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are relying on either the built in PDF viewers for the browsers or a plug in (which is a must for IE).  Because this is browser and/or plugin specific the experience may be different.  If you want consistent behavior you need to render the PDF server side.

For SharePoint this is usually done with Office Web Application (Word Web Viewer), which you can embed in a page.  If you don't have access to those you will need to rely on the browser behavior.